# How do you resize a text box height in simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I can figure out how to change the text box height with simple_form. Do i need to modifiy the css?

here is my code

```

```
.well/
= simple_form_for @document do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :content, :input_html => {:rows =>10} 
  = f.button :submit
```

```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
<%= f.input :message, :input_html => {:rows => 10} %>
```

Comment: isn't that the same as mine?

```  
    = f.input :content, :input_html => {:rows =>10}
```

Answer (score 1):

simple fix, change input to text area

```
= f.text_area :content, :input_html => {:rows => 10}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to tell simple_form that you are using a text_box, like this and it will work:

### haml

```
= f.input :content, as: :text, input_html: {rows: 9}
```

### html

```
<%= f.input :content, as: :text, input_html: {rows: 9} %>
```

Hope it helps :)